# just installed Docker on my Windows 10 Pro have a question on my version

Tags: docker

I'm new to using Docker and I have a quick question

so I go to command prompt and enter 
Docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

What is Build afacb8b?

Answer (score 2):

That's the [ID of the last commit for that version in their git repository](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/commit/afacb8b7f0d8d4f9d2a8e8736e9c993e672b41f3) - it's somewhat redundant with the version number (19.03.8), but might be useful for debugging.